# How to append String with comma in php

Tags: php, sql, string, loops

I have one loop for appending some strings to a variable. I need a best way of doing same. Currently I am pushing everything to an array then I implode it with comma. Is there any other best way of doing the same? Here is my code

```
$getDataProduct = "SELECT pm.*,crm.id sub_id, crm.name sub_name FROM `cp_reference_master` crm 
                    LEFT JOIN product_master pm on crm.parent_id = pm.category
                    Where crm.mode = 'item_type_subcat' AND pm.id = ".$data['id'];
$logger->debug("Get Product From Product Master for ".$data['id']);
$logger->trace("Query: ".$getDataProduct);
$result = $db->func_query($getDataProduct);
//echo '<pre>'; print_r($result); echo '</pre>';
foreach($result as $details){
    $result[0]['sub_ids'] = $details['sub_id'];
    $result[0]['sub_names'] = $details['sub_name'];

}
```

In my query I am getting 3 or 4 rows. except sub_id and sub_name everything is same. I need to append this sub_id and sub_name and put it in first row of sub_id and sub_name

Comment: That means : `$a = "a";  $a .= ", b";` now $a is : `a, b`

Comment: yes          that is what i am looking same string but each time the loop executes I need to add

Comment: Show us EXACTLY what you want the end result to be... edit your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$getDataProduct = "SELECT pm.*,crm.id sub_id, crm.name sub_name FROM `cp_reference_master` crm 
                LEFT JOIN product_master pm on crm.parent_id = pm.category
                Where crm.mode = 'item_type_subcat' AND pm.id = ".$data['id'];
$logger->debug("Get Product From Product Master for ".$data['id']);
$logger->trace("Query: ".$getDataProduct);
$result = $db->func_query($getDataProduct);
$sub_ids = '';
$sub_names = '';
foreach($result as $details){
$sub_ids = $sub_ids.', '. $details['sub_id'];
$sub_names = $sub_names.', '. $details['sub_name'];
$result[0]['sub_ids'] = $details['sub_id'];
$result[0]['sub_names'] = $details['sub_name'];
}
```

Now Every thing int the $sub_ids and $sub_names, no need to implode array with comma.

Comment: Thanks. This is the result I wated.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure this is the correct place your problem is but I will give it a try.

```
foreach($result as $details){
    $result_ids .= "," . $details['sub_id'];
    $result_sub_names .= "," . $details['sub_name'];
 }
```

This will create a comma first so you need to clear that with:

```
$result_sub_names = substr($result_sub_names,1);
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. This is what I wanted.